# UIActivityViewController crash on iPad landscapoe only app

Tags: ipad, landscape, uiactivityviewcontroller

I just added an UIActivityViewController to share some App data to Facebook, Twitter or email.
The popoverPresentationController is displayed and the listed activities can be selected and the content is shared without problems.
Crash happens when you tap on More... and then hit the done button in the presented empty activities list.
The activities are presented by:

```
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = cell;
    [[CliqmusicViewController instance] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the Done button is tapped i got the following exception:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIUserDefaultsActivityNavigationController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'**

The _UIUserDefaultsActivityNavigationController seems to be an SDK internal class, so there is no way to subclass or build a (category) for it.
Using 8.4 SDK.
Any thought? Thanks!

Comment: it is simple, your app (but at least your view controller which presents it) has to support, probably, both landscape and portrait orientations.

Comment: Sure, but this is not possible. App is designed to work in landscape only on iPad.

Comment: then you are probably in a deadlock for a while if you don't intent to adopt, because the Apple probably won't change this behaviour for developers' convenience, if they would change it at some point, that is for their pleasure only, but that is unpredictable.